# Why is this ternary operator syntax invalid?

Tags: python, ternary-operator

I am trying to write a simple ternary operator which would look like this in ruby:

`0 > 1 ? alice+=1 : bob+=1`

I have it written in python like this:

`alice += 1 if 0 > 1 else bob += 1`

This ternary operator throws an invalid syntax at `bob+=1`. Why is this happening, and how can I make the second operator execute along the same lines as the first?

Comment: You can only write *expressions* in ternary operators, not *statements*.

Comment: Because `bob += 1` is a _statement_, not an _expression_.

Comment: How can I go about rendering `bob+=1` an expression? And why is `alice+=1` an expression, but `bob+=1` a statement?

Comment: Both of those are augmented assignment statements, not expressions. It is unclear what you want.

Comment: Assignment can *never be an expression in Python*. You can wrap the logic in a function and call that, though (a function call is an expression)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ternary syntax is an *expression*; you've tried to use it as a one-line `if-then-else`.  You can pick the increment value, that comes from the RHS of the equation, such as:

```
alice += 1 if bob > 1 else 0
```

... but you can't change the assignment's target like this.  If you *really* need to do that, you can assign a custom tuple to the LHS `alice, bob`, but that seems overkill.  Just use the natural `if` statement

```
if 0 > 1:
    alice += 1
else:
    bob += 1
```

The final execution code will be that same, and the source stays more readable.

Comment: Alright this makes sense. So the ternary in Python is quite different from that of ruby? It seems more useful for the assignment of variables rather than the assessment of statements. Does python simply lack the ability to execute boolean logic like this in a streamlined fashion?

Comment: Right.  Most languages with something called a "ternary" operator use the legacy [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).  An expression-oriented language, such as C or Ruby, has the option of allowing a full statement as an expression.  Python and C chose not to go that far; Ruby did.

Comment: Python is quite capable of the logic path.  There is likely something in the rationale documents that explains why the ternary operator works this way.  I just haven't looked for it.

Comment: Right ... but I'm pretty sure that C doesn't allow an assignment in a ternary expression.  Neither does Python -- which allows `a = b = c = -1`, for example.

Comment: @Prune check out https://repl.it/JPW8/1
Personally, I hate allowing assignment as an expression.

Comment: However, an assignment in Python does *not* return a value; that cascaded assignment is simply syntactic convenience.  `print (bob = 1)` gets a syntax error, rather than `1`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for finding such a pithy `C` reference.

Comment: @Prune OK, point taken, I realize C is notorious for empirical results not being necessarily indicative of the standard... But I'm not well read on the C standards, so perhaps it *is* written somewhere "Assignment statements cannot be used in the ternary operator".